# TimePickerDialogをspinnerモードにしたい

Tags: android, java

javaからTimePickerDialogを呼び出すとclockモードになってしまうので、spinnerモードで呼び出す方法が知りたいです。

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    TimePickerDialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
            new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,int h, int m){
                    String time = String.format("%02d時%02d分",h,m);
                    TextView end = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endTime);
                    end.setText(time);
                }
            },hour,minute,true);
    timeDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TimePickerDialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
        AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker,int h, int m){
                String time = String.format("%02d時%02d分",h,m);
                TextView end = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endTime);
                end.setText(time);
            }
        },hour,minute,true);
timeDialog.show();
```

このように、コンストラクタの引数の2個目にHOLOテーマを設定するとスピナーになりますよ。古いので非推奨みたいですが。